# Array is having extra symbols other than which i added, trimming the array in iphone app using objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, trim

in my iphone app i am adding string values to the array first strSelectedDir value ill be 
xxx-jan16-2011-10.30AM  later its value ill be xxx-feb16-2011-02.30PM ,,i am adding these 2 values into the array arrDownloadedDirNames using the following code

```
 [arrDownloadedDirNames addObject:strSelectedDir];
```

but in the out put array some new line symbols(\n) and symbols like \ "" are coming as shown bellow

```
(
    "(\n    \"xxx-jan16-2011-10.30AM\"\n)",
    "xxx-feb16-2011-02.30PM"
)

but i want array should be like this with no extra symbols other than which are in the input string 

(
    xxx-jan16-2011-10.30AM ,
    xxx-feb16-2011-02.30PM
)
```

how can i do this, why extra symbols are added? how can i remove those
 please can any one help me,, thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your String is from a Parse or something right?
The extra symbols you see are called Escape Sequences:

\n = linebreake
\" = "

You can replace this Charakters pretty easy.

```
NSMutabeString *yourNewString = [NSMutabelString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrDownloadDirNames objectAtIndex:i]
[yourNewString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n    \""  withString:@""  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourNewString length])];
[yourNewString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"\n"  withString:@""  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourNewString length])];
```

Cheers
nettz